# Time format conversation In c

Tags: c, time, timezone, arduino, timezone-offset

I am working on time critical operation in c with arduino. I am reading time from RTC. My algorithm needs

```
 1. local solar time
 2. local time
 3. local standard time meridian
 4. equation of time.
 5. Greenwich mean time.
```

I read date and time from RTC . How can use time to convert to  calculation for above format.

Comment: Try to google the terms listed in your question.

Comment: Either [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) or [ICU4C](http://site.icu-project.org/) can be used to do time zone conversions.